# How to check if correct link is given

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I'm downloading a XML file from a server and for that I use the following code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];  // Load XML data from web

[data writeToFile:storePath atomically:TRUE];
```

Now how can I check if the link is the correct link with the XML? For example if they fill in www.google.com the data from that webpagina will be stored in `NSData *data`.

I'm searching for a way to check if the user gives the correct link.

Comment: check link contains .xml or not. see answer

Comment: The accurate solution for your scenario is to download data then verify if it's relevant to you or not.

Comment: You can use `NSXMLParser`. If `parserError==nil` it means the link contains valid XML otherwise it is not.

Comment: I'm using the GDataXML to parse

Answer (score 1):

Check URL is valid or not

```
- (BOOL)validateURL:(NSString *)url {
    NSString *urlRegEx =
    @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx]; 
    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:url];
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the link can change, so maybe its www.test.org today and tomorrow it could be www.stackoverflow.com/test if you know what I mean

Comment: check Sting contion .xml Substing in your url or not

Answer (score 1):

Like if Your XML link Generating on Runtime and You want to check whether it is for XML or not like

```
  if ([string rangeOfString:@".xml"].location == NSNotFound) {
          NSLog(@"No Xml Link Found");
        } else {
          NSLog(@"Xml Link Found");
        }

    Case 1: string = @"http://www.google.com";
    will Show this Log
              NSLog(@"No Xml Link Found");

    Case 2: string = @"http://www.google.com/live.xml";
    will Show this Log
              NSLog(@"Xml Link Found");
```

Comment: The problem is that they need to fill in a link linke www.google.com and I add the xml tags myself, so I add /test.xml to www.google.com because I use the link for different things not only for the XML

Comment: For your point of view just need to download and check means parse the xml